# I've been having a few issues with this pygame code

Tags: python, pygame

I have a few issues with this code. The main objective of the game is to have enemies coming from the top of the screen and to have the user type a word into the input box which will correspond to the enemies word.

My initial idea was to have the enemies saved as a class that can be used to call multiple enemies but I have had the issues that:

1. The enemies do not have any text written onto their box.
2. The enemies are drawn too many times and it looks weird.

The code is shown below:

```
class enemy(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,w,h,text,color):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.font = pg.font.SysFont("comicsansms",t5)
        self.textSurf = self.font.render(text, 10, red)
        self.image = pg.Surface((w,h))
        w = self.textSurf.get_width()
        h = self.textSurf.get_height()
        x = random.randint(110,1000)
        y = 0
        pg.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white,(x,y,w,h))
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects(text, self.font)
        textRect.center = ((x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)))
        gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)
        self.image.blit(self.textSurf,[w/2, h/2])
        self.text = a
```

the loop:

```
def gameLoop():
    enemyx = random.randint(100,900)
    enemyy = -600
    enemyw = 130
    enemyh = 50
    enemySpeed = 10
    enemyword = a
    gameDisplay.fill(bg_color)
    pg.display.update()
    End = False
    while not End:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                quit()
            button("Back", 10,10,130,50,D_orange, orange, gameIntro)
            pg.display.update()
        gameDisplay.fill(bg_color)
        button("Back", 10,10,130,50,D_orange, orange, gameIntro)
        enemy(enemyx,enemyy,enemyw,enemyh,white,enemyword)
        pg.display.update()
        enemyy +=2
        if enemyy >=850:
            enemyy = 0-enemyh
            enemyx = random.randint(100,900)
        pg.display.update()
```

a is corresponding to a random word taken from a dictionary.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `self.text = text` rather than `self.text = a`?

Comment: You have to swap the 5th and 6th parameter when creating `enemy`. It has to be `enemy(enemyx,enemyy,enemyw,enemyh,enemyword,white)`

Comment: thanks can't believe I was being that stupid.

Answer (score 0):

I got the parameters the wrong way around which lead to the issue of the enemies not being drawn. The text is still however correct as I want the text to be a random word, which is saved as "a". Thank you @Rabbid76 for seeing and answering my mistake.